# Definition of Regressor

Tags: machine-learning

Hi i have been learning Machine Learning for over six months, and I started to see the term Regressor and can 't really google it out for an exact definetion.

I fully understand logistic regression and linear regression..but just can't figure out this term,..(and sometimes so many terms coming out from ML but they more or less refers to similar things..)

I just got this answer from wiki:

The independent variables, also known in a statistical context as regressors, represent inputs or causes, i.e., potential reasons for variation or, in the experimental setting, the variable controlled by the experimenter.

Is this correct - the learning of ML, to me, really is so much slightly varying terminologies... (which can be completely absent in one course or framework, and suddenly they appear elsewhere..)

Answer (score 20):

Yes, your understanding is correct. **Feature, independent variable, explanatory variable, regressor, covariate, or predictor** are all names of the variables that are used to predict the **target, outcome, dependent variable, regressand, or response**. The terminology is ambiguous as it comes from different fields: statistics, econometrics, and machine learning.

Comment: In first group: add covariate and predictor (both of which are used in various other senses),  controlling variable. In second group: add response. Trying to produce a complete list is likely to be futile, but all these terms seem commonly used.

Comment: @NickCox good point, updated.

Comment: I might add “factor” to the list of predictor types, though it does imply a categorical variable in particular.

Comment: @Dave never heard it used & sounds super confusing. As Nick Cox said, there is no point in trying to make the list comperhensive.

Comment: Various possible meanings of factor include (1) whatever is produced by factor analysis (long-standing) (2) another name for whatever is not a response (e.g. J.W. Tukey, circa 1977) (3) a specific name for a categorical variable (standard now in much statistical software).

Answer (score 0):

An explanatory variable is the variable in its raw form.  A regressor is the variable as it appears in a regression equation.  Hence, the regressor is the explanatory variable if used as is, but its transformation if any transformations are applied. I think that the term 'regressor' applies specifically to regression equations, and would not apply otherwise.

Comment: I have often seen the transform of something called an explanatory variable. The gradation between "what others say in various places" and "my terminology which is clear and consistent" is a wide grey zone.

Comment: Agreed!  That explanation was provided by Fox, John [2016] Applied Regression Analysis and Generalised Linear Models, 3rd ed. Sage, Thousand Oaks, CA.  It made sense to me, and I adopted that interpretation for a book that I have written.  That is, the explanatory variable is that which was delivered, prior to any transformation.